# ISPconfig maildir migration

Tags: email, webserver, migration

I want to migrate my email accounts from old server to my new one with ISPconfig 3.1 and I want to import Maildir file into my new server. But I think, it has a different format. When I create email account on another domain with ISP config, it is stored in : /var/vmail/anotherdomain.com/info (email is info@anotherdomain.com) But from my old provider, when I extracted maildir into domain.com location, I see numbers (204073) instead of real emails like info@ and In ISPconfig I don't see any email addresses and any email domain.

So how can I import emails in ISPconfig?

And where are passwords for these addresses stored? Because I don't know email accounts passwords and I can't edit them, beacuse users are using them.

Or exist any better way, how to migrate emails between servers?